# Google OAuth 2.0 what in the code paramater should i pass to my authentication function

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

Hello I have an nodejs http server that if someone goes into [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login) they get redirected to an google oauth2 url and then back at my site with a code.
When a user gets back at my site with [www.example.com/?code=4/SomeCodeHere&scope=SomeScopeHere](http://www.example.com/?code=4/SomeCodeHere&scope=SomeScopeHere)
I want to get what part of the url is the code needed for authentication and how should it be formatted %2 or / etc

Answer (score 1):

When you are being redirected back to the url the following url

[www.example.com/?code=4/SomeCodeHere&scope=SomeScopeHere](http://www.example.com/?code=4/SomeCodeHere&scope=SomeScopeHere)

The code parameter contains **authorization_code** grant which is equal to ***4/SomeCodeHere*** in this particular case. Here are the following steps that you will need to complete:

1. Your browser client should pass **authorization_code** to your server (E.g. using HTTP post or get)
2. Backend then must make a request to Google API and send that code to obtain **access_token**, additionally you will receive **id_token** which will contain basic user profile information.
3. After receiving response from google you must verify it's signature to be sure that the response actually came from google. It can be done by computing and comparing the id_token JWT signatures
4. If everything is as expected then backend will can notify browser about successful authentication.

Below is the abstract diagram describing the whole process. (Authorization server and resource server in your case are the same server):

[image]